# Crash App with FirebaseInitProvider AndroidStudio

Tags: android, firebase

y have a problem when i compile my apps because i have this Error, i have tried all possibility please help me !

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.eclixal.io-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Thank for your help

Cdt Alexandre, sorry for my english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using, **Clean Project** and then **Rebuild Project**.
And if, it doesn't work.. try this one,
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html